# Restore a bacpac file from blob store to Azure SQL database with Powershell in Azure Runbooks

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, azure-sql-database

I am attempting to run the following PowerShell script to restore a `.bacpac` file to an Azure SQL database, but I am getting an error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

How can I fix the Powershell script to get it to run in Azure Automation Runbook?

```
$importRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseImport -ResourceGroupName "RG1" `
   -ServerName "sql001.database.windows.net" `
   -DatabaseName "WideWorldImportersDB" `
   -DatabaseMaxSizeBytes "50000" `
   -StorageKeyType "StorageAccessKey" `
   -StorageKey "key1" `
   -StorageUri "https://blob001.blob.core.windows.net/container/WideWorldImporters-Standard.bacpac" `
   -Edition "Standard" `
   -ServiceObjectiveName "P6" `
   -AdministratorLogin "login" `
   -AdministratorLoginPassword $(ConvertTo-SecureString -String "123!" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Comment: Can you run your PowerShell script on-premise?

Comment: Besides, could you please provide the error message in detail?

Comment: Have you refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-import-from-bacpac-powershell